# List<>.Exists() doesn't exist in WP7?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, windows-phone-7

Unless I'm missing something here Exists() doesn't exist in WP7? If this is true does someone know of an equivalent?

Comment: can you post the query that you're trying to write?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By looking at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.95).aspx) it seems it doesn't exist. You can simulate it with:

```
 myList.Any(p => p == something);
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I knew there had to be another way. I guess LINQ is cool like that. Thanks +1.

Comment: @loyalpenguin At Microsoft probably decided to rationalize a little the API, because much of it was from the pre-generics and then pre-LINQ era.

Answer (score 3):

.Any()
.Contains()
Should be working